# How to deploy/host sencha touch app on server

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

Hi I have created an sencha touch app which i want to host as web instead of creating a native app package and then deploy at different app stores. I have used sencha touch 2.2.1. 
Can any one help me on how to deploy my application on server. Steps for deploying sencha touch app on server would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Sencha Cmd, read the [Using Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/command_app) guide in the Touch documentation.

In a nutshell, run *sencha app build production* and then copy the build to your web server (via FTP, for example).

Comment: thanks arturakay,but my server is located at other place,don't i be needing sencha cmd and sencha touch there. And to be sure i just have to copy the build folder inside my application on the server instead of whole application. right..!

Comment: Correct - copy the output (in the build/production/MyApp folder) to your web server. You don't need Cmd or Touch on the webserver... Touch is included in your build.